# Mac Yosemite & Safari 8

Tags: osx-yosemite

Is there a way to organize reading list into folders? I want to organize my mac without using the ever note application. It is starting to get confusing having items on ever note, reading list, and bookmarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.

If you need to keep you reading lists for more than just a quick glance back, use bookmarks instead - then you have the full suite of tools at your fingertips, including nested folders.